# Error: write EPIPE node8

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, node8.2, node8.4

This is https://github.com/mapbox/ecs-watchbot/pull/205/files#diff-644d8ede25bb88427ccf4229d03bba1bR19 breaking the test with

```
[worker] waitFor, exit 0
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: write EPIPE
at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:864:14)
```

[Here](https://github.com/mapbox/ecs-watchbot/blob/container-recycling/test/worker.test.js#L114), when run locally npm run test [this](https://github.com/mapbox/ecs-watchbot/blob/container-recycling/test/worker.test.js#L279) fails.

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report?

Comment: a question. :-(

Comment: :) You see, your external links have a lot of code to read through. I bet, little people have time to do this. So, if you want any help, please, try to narrow down your question and add only relevant code in here in your questioin body.

Comment: it is just one line adding which travis and local error differently, the first link.